# Forcing desktop environment out of tty2

Tags: gnome, tty

A simple question here. By default Ubuntu 18.04 runs consoles tty1-6, where tty1-2 are then used for the desktop environment.

When I am loaded to a gnome login screen (it's on tty1), I can log into my user account and quickly press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to tty2 before it gets occupied with DE. What do you think then happens? Well, tty2 is now in a default tty mode (just like tty3-6), and DE is now accessible by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Thus, here is my question. Does this move force my machine to start an additional tty (because usually they are created only up to tty6)? And also does it need a sensible amount of additional resources for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'sensible'. Answer your own tty question by looking for yourself with `ps`.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK tty7 is used for Xserver and gnome login screen.
Consoles tty1-6 are always available and you can reach them with Ctrl+Alt+F1-6 anytime without the magic you describe here.

Comment: Starting from Ubuntu 17.10 (and I'm using 18.04) tty1-2 are used for gnome desktop environment, and there are tty3-6 left.

Answer (score 2):

Those TTYs are already present. It's just that nothing runs on them *yet*. The default configuration is to run getty on TTYs 1-6, but systemd attempts to optimize by starting getty on a TTY only when someone actually switches to it. So GDM gets to start on TTY1, and start user sessions on TTY2 and so on.

```
$ pgrep getty
# no output, switch to TTY3 and back
$ pgrep getty
18953
# getty started on TTY3
```

Similarly, you can start additional programs on other TTYs to your heart's content (well, up to as many as are created):

```
$ ls /dev/tty[0-9]* | wc -l
64
$ sudo systemctl start getty@63
$ pgrep getty                             
18953
19578
# Another getty, now on TTY63
$ sudo lsof /dev/tty3                     
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
agetty  18953 root    0u   CHR    4,3      0t0 1044 /dev/tty3
agetty  18953 root    1u   CHR    4,3      0t0 1044 /dev/tty3
agetty  18953 root    2u   CHR    4,3      0t0 1044 /dev/tty3
$ sudo lsof /dev/tty63
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
agetty  19578 root    0u   CHR   4,63      0t0 1104 /dev/tty63
agetty  19578 root    1u   CHR   4,63      0t0 1104 /dev/tty63
agetty  19578 root    2u   CHR   4,63      0t0 1104 /dev/tty63
```